# Prevent cursor to jump last while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a text field which has length of 6 and when I typed something in to the text box and the cursor jump to the end of the text.
"Ex : 1234"

I have entered the text and second position and cursor jump to last instead of staying there.

Comment: Your cursor jumps when you type in a textbox? Am I reading this correct? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: yeah what you understood is correct

Comment: That's not normal behaviour, can you make a JSFiddle with your code so we can repeat the behaviour please?

Comment: It is not normal behaviour, You must be doing something with that textfield may a javascript function validation etc. Please post brief code here.

Comment: @chandu please post the code following [this SO guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)